# Will inout ports used only as in or out be optimized?

Tags: fpga, vhdl, vivado

I am writing a VHDL design in Xilinx Vivado. I received an example code for an FMC card where all the ports are designated as `inout`. If I use an `inout` port only as `in` or `out` in the rest of my architecture, will Vivado optimize the port to the appropriate type during synthesis? Or will it stay an `inout` port?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In all likelihood, yes, the `inout` will be optimised away.

In fact in almost all devices there are no internal tri-state buffers on routing, so `inout` ports usually get converted into a series of multiplexers.

If you have an `inout` port always being driven inside a module, then the logic will simplify down.

However, if you connect two `inout` ports together, and both of them are using it as an output, it may or may not result in a compiler error. If you are lucky the synthesiser will see that a net being driven by two drivers and error out. If you are unlucky, you will infer logic that optimises one of the drivers away and then you'll have a debugging headache on your hands.

If you have a port which is output only, stick to using an `output` type. If it is input only, then you can safely use `inout` or `input`, but better stick to `input` to make things easier to follow.